# how to use while loop in generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux-saga, es6-generator

i'm new to generator function and trying execute while loop inside it.

```
export function* findRandomData(list, name) {
  let searchList = true;
  const formattedName = name
    .replace(new RegExp('_', 'g'), ' ')
    .toLowerCase();

  const indexesToSearch = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    indexesToSearch.push(i);
  }

  let viableId;
  // Search through results
  while (searchList) {
    // If there are no results left then finish
    if (indexesToSearch.length === 0) {
      searchList = false;
      throw new Error('Could not find id');
    }

    // Find a random number that has not been selected already, then remove
    const randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * indexesToSearch.length);
    indexesToSearch.splice(randomPosition, 1);

    let title = list[randomPosition].title;
    viableId = list[randomPosition].id;

    const eligible = yield call(
      isEligibleVideo,
      title,
      formattedName,
      viableId
    );

    if (eligible) {
      searchList = false;
    }
  }

  return viableId;
}
```

but it return `null` even though the while loop have not completed for search.

`const data = yield call(findRandomData, resp['res'], name);`

**Error**
`Error: Could not find id at findRandomData`

what is it that i'm doing wrong

Comment: I notice you're assigning to `eligible` but testing `eligibleVideo` — are those meant to be the same?

Comment: yeah its eligible, edit mistake. `eligible` returns the value. i tried with normal function it works but not in generator function

Comment: You're not accessing any of the values of `indexesToSearch`.

Comment: `indexesToSearch` is for checking the position in the list once the position is randomly generated its been removed so that it wont recheck the same data twice

Comment: I thought as much, but the way you're currently using it after it's filled is only to get its length and to remove a random element: something's missing. Consider what happens if `randomPosition` is assigned 3 twice, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a value to viableId variable when you declare it, for example :
let viableId = ""; // if your variable will receive a string value

Or give it a number value (generally people uses 0) if you're working with numbers.